# How do these terms cancel in infinite geometric series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

below I am told that terms with alpha in them cancel (in the third line) due to the second line possessing all of the terms with alpha that the first line does. However, this contradicts with my notion of infinite sums. I imagine that the top line keeps on summing terms forever, but it is always one term ahead of the bottom line, so at no point does the bottom line contain enough terms with alpha to cancel the last term in the sum of the top line. I am a programmer, so I am thinking of two infinite loops being initialized which correspond to the two sums in the first and second lines, and the first loop being initialized prior to the second, so at no point is the difference between these loops just one.
Therefore, I imagine that these lines are not able to cancel. I am not sure how to think about the notion of an infinite sum here such that the terms cancel in this proof of the infinite geometric series formula. I would appreciate some explanation as to these matters.
thanks
[image]

Comment: I think reading any analysis textbook (for example, "Principles of Mathematical Analysis" by Rudin) will help - at least check definition of infinite sum. Thinking of series as loops can and likely will lead to confusion and wrong statements.

Comment: This is well spotted. The difference at $n$th stage is $1-\alpha^n$. To conclude what they concluded, you need to also assert that $\alpha^n\to 0$ when $n\to\infty$ (which is true for $|\alpha|<1$).

Comment: Just check it out: say $\alpha=2$, if you blindly follow the above logic you would get convinced that $1+2+4+8+16+\ldots=-1$. which is nonsense. But $2^n$ does not converge to $0$ as $n\to\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Of course if $ | \alpha | \geq 1$ than series is divergent due
$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}| {\alpha}^i | \geq \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} 1$ That what have you written is start of proof of such infinite sum for $ | \alpha | < 1$

Further $1= x- \alpha x =x(1- \alpha) $ then $ x = \frac{1}{1-\alpha} $ that means. For other numbers substracting is illegal due $\infty - \infty $ case